# Mutually Exclusive Bootstrap Checkbox Switches as Layer Control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, css, bootstrap-framework

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/s537t380/3/) with two checkboxes using Bootstrap Switch that changes the layer visibility in Leaflet.

I would like them to be mutually exclusive, i.e neither of them can be on or off at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In the onClick functions for each, put some code that checks the state of the other check box. If the state of the other checkbox is checked, then perform the code to uncheck and remove the layer and load in the one you want. Apply the same logic for the other check boxes onclick function.

Comment: Thanks, where would the `onClick` go in my example?

Comment: Sorry, looks likein  your example you would be putting the logic in the onSwitchChange functions.